# Closure alternatives

Tags: javascript

I run into many cases where I find myself needing to do something akin to the following

```
function main() {
    var x = "Something";

    foo('do stuff', function bar(stuffResponse) {
        var y = x + stuffResponse;
    });
}
```

I.e. a closure where my callback function needs the variable `x` I defined previously. This bugs me however as I don't like that my `bar` function depends a variable outside of itself, but most of all because I *much* prefer writing my code like this instead...

```
function main() {
    var x = "Something";

    foo('do stuff', bar);
}

function bar(stuffResponse) {
    var y = x + stuffResponse;
}
```

But obviously if I do this `bar` has no idea what `x` is anymore. Is there a clean way to achieve the latter style whilst retaining the former's functionality?

Comment: I see no reason to avoid relying on a closure. But, you can always pass `x` as an argument to `bar()`

Comment: This is a simple example where it isn't really a problem, when it gets more complicated and I need more stuff inside my closure it becomes hard to follow. And I can't pass `x` as an argument to `bar()`, its used as a callback function

Comment: The question is if you really need `x` defined in a scope outside of the closure (your snippet does not demonstrate this need). Can you update your snippet to show something a little closer to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Can't you just define `x` outside of `main()`?

Comment: You *can* pass it even if it's a callback. `var x = 1; function bar(x, stuffResponse) {var y = x + stuffResponse;}.bind(null, x)`

Comment: I could @BenHillier but I don't want a lot of globals that don't need to be globals, either. Also if `main()` was used inside a loop the value of the global could change repeatedly before the function that needed its current value gets called

Comment: @EdwardSammutAlessi You do want this to be a global; you're just trying to convince yourself otherwise. If you want a variable defined somewhere else to be available in a stand-alone function, that is, per definition, a global

Comment: What I wanted was what @Dencker suggested. Thanks, I had known about `.bind(this)` but didn't know it could take additional arguments to prepend to the function. If you submit as an answer I'd happily select as my answer

Comment: So I guess you mean, is there any way to have access to a variable when you don't have access to it?

Comment: Closures are very ideomatic in Javascript!

Comment: Your question title refers to "pitfall". What pitfall are you referring to, other than the fact you are not emotionally comfortable with closures?

Comment: "Pitfall" was the wrong word to use. I do not have any issue with closures, there are many use cases for them and I use them regularly myself. I just want to achieve the functionality of a closure, without using a closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, what you're trying to achieve can be done by binding the variable to your callback. That'll give you a copy of the value instead of referencing the original variable:

```
function main() {
    var x = "Something";

    foo('do stuff', function bar(x, stuffResponse) {
        var y = x + stuffResponse;
    }.bind(null, x));
}
```

You can also bind `this` instead of `null`. However, it doesn't really make sense since you're not using `this`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed, a way to neatly pass a variable to a callback, without creating a global or using a closure.

Comment: It's massively unclear what the objective of doing this is, or why it answers what the OP's question was, which I don't know.

Comment: @torazaburo I guess OPs objective is to get rid of the possibility that - in the asynchronous nature of JS - if something alters `x` when defined in the scope outside of the callback before it gets called, it'll yield inconsistent results.  So I guess he wanted to use the _current_ value of `x` into the callback, not caring when it's going to be called.

Answer (score 3):

A variable can be available in any of these ways:

1. Passed as a parameter to a function.
2. Declared within the function.
3. Declared globally
4. Available from an enclosing scope.

You have to decide which of these you want to make `x` available. There's nothing wrong with 4, at all. 2 doesn't apply here. 3 should be avoided. 1 is a reasonable alternative depending on the situation.

Comment: I have no problem with closures, but it is sometimes undesirable for me to use them, and I was searching for alternatives. I don't understand what my emotions have to do with looking for better ways to do things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in call function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call and do something like this:

```
function main() {
  var x = "so clean";

  function foo(cb) {
    cb.call(null, x);
  }

  foo(bar);
}

function bar(something) {
  console.log(something);
}
```